# Assign document.body.style.backgroundColor to a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, background-color

I'm making a simple color changer.
And I assigned  `document.body.style.backgroundColor` to valuable `backgroundColor`. When I `console.log(backgroundColor)` , I can see it's working but background color doesn't change.
So I just deleted the variable `backgroundColor` and put `document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];` and then it works! But I can't understand why it doesn't work when I assigned `document.body.style.backgroundColor` to a variable as below code.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    let backgroundColor =  document.body.style.backgroundColor ;
    backgroundColor  = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  
console.log(backgroundColor)

})
```

Comment: To understand this behavior, read about difference between copying by value and referencing to a value: https://javascript.info/object-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing that you are just copying (saving) the literal value of the `document.body.style.backgroundColor`, not a thing to point at that. so assigning a new value to the variable doesn't affect the `document.body.style.backgroundColor`.

You are just changing the value again:

```
backgroundColor  = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

Comment: Ahh!!  Thank you so much!! I feel so stupid....I didn't even understand these kind of super basic stuff...

Comment: Happy it helped ^^. also you can mark an answer as accepted, by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: omg I didn't even know how to accept  answer,...Again, thank you so much!!